# Ejecutar powershell sin usar scripts

Tags: vb.net, powershell

Tengo el siguiente código que ejecuta un powershell

```
Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = New Collection(Of PSObject)()

Using powerShell As Management.Automation.PowerShell = Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create()
   Using runspace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()

      runspace.Open()
      powerShell.Runspace = runspace      

      powerShell.AddScript(script, False)

      results = powerShell.Invoke()

      powerShell.AddCommand(nombrecomando).AddParameters(parametros)

      results = powerShell.Invoke()

   End Using

End Using
```

Donde la variable script es un string que contiene el código de un fichero .ps1 que tiene funciones de este tipo:

```
Function AsociarUsuario
{
    param ( 
         [string]$User
        ,[string]$Controlador
        ,[string]$RemoteRoutingAddress
        )
    
      Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity $User -DomainController $Controlador -RemoteRoutingAddress $RemoteRoutingAddress                   

}
```

La variable nombrecomando es el nombre de la función (AsociarUsuario) y la de parámetros un listado con los parámetros que espera la función de powershell (User, Controlador y RemoteRoutingAddress).

Hasta ahora ejecutaba este código sobre un servidor con una versión de Exchange antigua que permitía Full Language y ahora tengo que ejecutarlo en un nuevo servidor con una versión de Exchange que tiene Non Language y no permite el uso de scripts, me gustaría saber como puedo cambiar el código para ejecutar el powershell sin usar scripts y así que funcione en el nuevo servidor.

Comment: Propongo una alternativa.  Si lo permite el administrador del servidor es posible definir el $PROFILE de tal suerte que corra automáticamente cuando Powershell se inicia.  Esto requiere un fichero .ps1 para contener todas las funciones que deben ser accesibles. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/how-to-make-use-of-powershell-profile-files/

Comment: Hola Walter, gracias por tu respuesta. Finalmente no conseguí solucionarlo de esa manera.
Lo que hice es crear un comando con el nombre Enable-RemoteMailbox (Comando = new Command("Enable-RemoteMailbox ")) y le pasé los parametros (Comando.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("User", "valor"))) para después añadirlo al powershell (PowerShell.Commands.AddCommand(Comando)) e invocarlo.